# Sorting lines with numbers and word characters

Tags: sorting, vim

I recently wrote a simple utility in Perl to count words in a file to determinate its frequency, that's how many times it appears.

It's all fine, but I'd like to sort the result to make it easier to read. An output example would be:

```
4:an
2:but
5:does
10:end
2:etc
2:for
```

As you can see, it's ordered by word, not frequency. But with a little help  of `:sort` I could reorganize that. Using `n`, numbers like 10 go to the right place (even though it start with 1), plus a little `!` and the order gets reversed, so the word that appears more is the first one.

```
:sort! n
10:end
5:does
4:an
2:for
2:etc
2:but
```

The problem is: when the number is repeated it gets sorted by word — which is nice — but remember, the order was reversed!

```
for -> etc -> but
```

How can I fix that? Will I have to use some Vim scripting to iterate over each line checking whether it starts with the previous number, and marking relevant lines to sort them after the number changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `vim` `:help sort`:

```
The details about sorting depend on the library function used.  There is no
guarantee that sorting is "stable" or obeys the current locale.  You will have
to try it out.
```

As a result, you might want to perform the sorting in your Perl script instead; it wouldn't be hard to extend your Perl `sort` to be stable, see `perldoc sort` for entirely too many details.

If you just want this problem finished, then you can replace your `:sort` command with this:

`!sort -rn --stable` (it might be easiest to use Shift-V to visually select the lines first, or use a range for the sort, or something similar, but if you're writing `vim` scripts, none of this will be news to you. :)

Comment: Initially I thought about doing it straight in Perl, though I just realized this when I had already redirected the output to a Vim buffer. I ended up asking how to do it, you know, for the sake of learning something new — I'll probably need this in the future. Thanks for making everything clear!

Answer (score 4):

```
tac | sort -nr
```

does this, so select the lines with shift+V and use !

Comment: tac! Nice way to solve this! But do you believe even though I know this utility, I don't have it installed! So… Perl in action. Source code for tac: `print reverse <>` :P Thanks a lot @raylu, it's a pity I can't give the correct state for two answers, nor upvote twice.

Comment: Well, --stable solves the problem more generally and more efficiently.

Comment: @sidyll, I've wished for multiple-upvotes several times. :) But don't fret, I can upvote @raylu's answer too. :)

Comment: But this is a very clever solution too. Thanks @sarnold! ;-)